# Locating html elements through xpath in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am new to Selenium and trying to access and click 'Image' link on Google page, once it has searched some string. But I am unable to do this. Following is in Selenium Python:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get ('http://google.com')
q = driver.find_element_by_xpath ("id('gbqfq')")     # Search text box
q.send_keys ('Apple')
driver.find_element_by_name ('btnG').click()

# I am now going to access the 'Image' link through following comamnd
driver.find_element_by_xpath ("id('hdtb_msb')/x:div[2]/x:a").click()
```

Error is below:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: u'The given selector id(\'hdtb_msb\')/x:div[2]/x:a is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:\nInvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression id(\'hdtb_msb\')/x:div[2]/x:a because of the following error:\n[Exception... "An attempt was made to create or change an object in a way which is incorrect with regard to namespaces"
```

My questions:
1.  Why is this error coming (I am using xpath Checker to get the xpath)?
2.  What are other possible ways to access this link?

Thanks already!

After my research:

It looks like I have to catch the handle of the current page loaded ? Please help me, I am totally new.

Comment: I will take a detail lesson there. But here I am using "XPath Checker" and which is able to find the particular element (I am able to test it). I don't understand why is this happening then ?

Comment: @user1177636 - It would be more helpful if you told him what was wrong.

Comment: Hah, looks like I already left a snarky comment on one of his other questions. Fair enough.

Comment: I do not know what `x:` means in XPath.

Comment: use CSS!  It's faster and cleaner!

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the namespaces (ie. The x:)

Comment: I believe this is the solution, because I also encountered the same issue today, and it is resolved by simply removing the namespace "x:". However, I don't know why the XPath given by XPath Checker has this "x" thing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are trying to search for xpath  but maybe you are not passing a valid value; generally the syntax of the xpath is this one: `.//*[@id='hdtb-msb']/div[2]/a`

I went to google page and I check the image for example and this is its xpath: `.//*[@id='hplogo']`

In any case I advice you to download firebug and firepath for firefox and via this tools you retrieve the xpath that you need